# The rate of change of the distance from the plane to the radar station

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

#### Problem statement:

A plane flying with constant speed of 4 km/min passes over a ground radar station at an altitude of 6 km and climbs at an angle of 35 degrees. At what rate, in km/min, is the distance from the plane to the radar station increasing 6 minutes later?

Hint: The law of cosines for a triangle is $c^2=a^2+b^2− 2ab \cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the sides of length $a$ and $b$.

---

Okay, so following the typical related rates algorithm:

Identify the problem at hand by drawing a picture. I did that. It appears to me that after the plane passes over the ground station, we get an angle between the measures a and b of 90 + 35 degrees.

Awesome.

Now, let's build a table of values:
$$
a = 6\,\mathrm{km}\\
a' = 0 \quad \text{(duh)}\\
b = b'\cdot t = 4\cdot 6 = 24\\
b' = 4\,\mathrm{km}/\mathrm{min}\\
t' = 6min\\
c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \sqrt{36+24} = 2\sqrt{15} \approx 2.78316\\
c' = ?
$$

Okay, let's differentiate the law of cosines, which is given to us in form of a hint:

$2cc' = 2aa' + 2bb' - \frac{du}{dt}$

$
u = 2ab\cos(\theta)$

$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{ds}{dt} \cdot \cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta)\cdot(2ab)$

$\frac{ds}{dt} = 0\cdot ab + (a'b + b'a)$

And so now we rewind:
$\frac{du}{dt} = \left[ \left(0 \cdot ab + \left(a'b + b'a \right) \right) \right] \cdot \cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta) \cdot 2ab $

And so:

$2cc' = 2aa' + 2bb' - \left[ \left(0 \cdot ab + \left(a'b + b'a \right) \right) \right] \cdot \cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta) \cdot 2ab $

---

Boom, boom. Let's substutute what we know

$2\left(2 \sqrt{15} \right)(c') = 2(6)(0) + 2(24)(4) - \left[ \left(0\cdot (6)(24) + \left((0)(24) +  (4)(6) \right) \right) \right] \cdot \cos(125^\circ) - \sin(125^\circ) \cdot 2(4)(24)$

---

Now what? Well, evaluate. Not sure if that's going to yield the right answer. But I don't think that it will.

Please help! I don't know how to solve this kind of problem! It seems my solution/process is incorrect!

Comment: Oh André, where oh where have you gone. I need to send you a fruit basket or something. 

I'd hate to know what kind of problems stump you for an hour.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need someone to help me find out why my answer is wrong :( What's the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: Where did you get 140 degrees?

Comment: The sum of 90 + 35. So the plane is flying horizontally, then as soon as it passes over the ground station, it begins climbing at 35 degrees. So it is at a 90 degree angle, then it adds another 35 to... oh, 125 degrees! ^_^. Okay I fixed it.

Comment: Please write $140^\circ$ (`140^\circ` or similar) if you mean $140$ degrees, because $\cos 140$ means the cosine of $140$ *radians*.

Comment: Why are you using the cosine law here?

Comment: Who downvoted me? Could I have a justification for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use your notation. Let $c=c(t)$ be the distance from the plane to the radar station at time $t$. Let $b$ be the distance from the plane to the point where the climb began. Then
$$c^2=36+b^2-12b\cos \theta=36+b^2+12b\sin\phi,\tag{1}$$
where $\theta=125^\circ$ and $\phi=35^\circ$. Differentiating, we get
$$2c\frac{dc}{dt}=2b\frac{db}{dt}+12\sin\phi\frac{db}{dt}.\tag{2}$$
"Freeze" at time $6$ minutes after the climb began. We know everything on the right-hand side of (2), since at that instant $b=(6)(4)$.

We need to calculate $c$ at time $t=6$. Equation (1) does that, with $b=24$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks okay for the most part; you've just made some mistakes.  A couple points:

1. $t'$ means the rate at which $t$ changes with respect to *itself*.  This is of course just 1.
2. Keep track of what's constant before breaking out the product rule, which can cause your formulae to explode.  In the expression $2 a b \cos(\theta)$, both $a$ and $\cos(\theta)$ are simply constants, so it's quite easy to differentiate.

Comment: Okay, so I shouldn't completely differentiate the formula before plugging in numbers? Would you mind editing my post and fixing the problem?

Comment: Just notice the difference between constant and non-constant.

Comment: Okay. Fixed some numbers.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your table of values, $c$ **isn’t** $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$; the correct formula is

$$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta}\;,$$

which in this case is

$$c=\sqrt{6^2+(4t)^2-2\cdot6\cdot4t\cdot\cos 125°}=\sqrt{36+16t^2-48t\cos125°}\;.$$

The differentiation is easier if we start with the square of that, and we get $$2cc'=32t-48\cos125°\;,$$ or $$c'=\frac{16t-24\cos 125°}c\;.$$ At $t=6$ we have $c\approx 27.87813$ km and hence $c'\approx 3.93734$ km/min.

Note that with this approach you’d have been less likely to get lost in the differentiation (e.g., forgetting that $a$ and $\cos\theta$ are constants).

Comment: Where did you get 135?

Comment: @alvonellos: Sorry: that’s a typo and should be $125°$ everywhere. Fixed now.

Comment: Shouldn't the $\cos$ be a $\sin$?

Comment: @copper.hat: No; $\cos\theta$ is a constant in this calculation.

Comment: It still says that's incorrect in the sample problem.

Comment: I'm missing something, if the plane is flying at 4 km/min., how can the distance from the station be increasing faster than that?

Comment: @alvonellos: It’s also obviously impossible, since the speed must be less than $4$ km/min. I apparently hit a wrong key in calculating $c$ originally, and was too busy juggling answers to three questions at once to notice how silly the answer was.

Comment: Nope. Still wrong, @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @alvonellos: Yes; I’m having trouble hitting the right keys tonight. This time I actually checked the result that I was copying and pasting, and it is at least possible.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use calculus?

At the moment in question, the plane is downrange from the radar station $24\cos(35^\circ)$ km at an altitude of  $(6+24\cdot\sin(35^\circ)) $ km.  So, $\theta$, the angle of elevation of the plane as seen from the radar station is given by:$$\theta=\tan^{-1}\frac{6+24\cdot\sin(35^\circ)}{24\cos(35^\circ)}$$ $\theta$ is obviously greater than $35^\circ$.

The plane is still climbing at $35^\circ$ at 4 km/ min.  The component of its velocity along the line of sight from the radar station is:$$V_{los}=4\cdot\cos(\theta-35^\circ)$$

Comment: I like this solution.

Comment: Of course this is really just *hiding* the calculus.  It's the linearity of the derivative that allows us to talk about a velocity being a vector that has components in directions.

Comment: From a Physics point of view, one might say that the calculus approach hides the physical fact about the component of velocity.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury: You are correct, of course, but I think the above approach is much better at giving an intuition for the problem that is hidden by the formulaic approach in the question. Frankly, I am bewildered by the OPs approach.

Comment: Hey. to the person with a hammer. all the world looks like a nail...

Comment: @AndréNicolas, we have to do one of three things: either take position as fundamental and define velocity as the derivative, or take velocity as fundamental and define position as the integral, or take them as *a priori* unrelated and posit "the velocity happens to be the derivative of the position" as a law of nature.  Personally I favor the first approach.

Comment: Who knows if nature is even continuous...

Comment: If you start with the velocity, and along the way you take a derivative to ***get*** a velocity, doesn't that mean that you must have done an integration as well?

Answer (score 0):

This seems way too complicated. I must be missing something.

[image]

We have $x(t) = 4t \cos \theta$, $y(t) = 6+4t \sin \theta$. Hence the distance from the radar station is $d(t)^2 = x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 = 48\,t\,\sin\left( \theta\right) +16\,{t}^{2}+36$.

Taking the square root and differentiating gives
$d'(t) = \frac{48\,{\sin}\left( \theta\right) +32\,t}{2\,\sqrt{48\,t\,\mathrm{sin}\left( \theta\right) +16\,{t}^{2}+36}}$.

Substituting $t=6$ gives:
$d'(6) = \frac{48\,\sin\left( \theta\right) +192}{2\,\sqrt{288\,\sin\left( \theta\right) +612}}$.

This gives me, roughly, $d'(6) \approx 3.94$.

Comment: It's not that complicated?

Comment: @MichaelFulton: I meant the OP's approach was complicated (to me).